# Not able to see icons in side navigation bar in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, navigationbar

I'm not able to see the icons I am providing in the menu item to see it inside the navigation bar.
Below is the code of the menu `main_menu.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/home_nav" android:title="Home" android:icon="@drawable/home"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/profile" android:title="Profile" android:icon="@drawable/profile"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/generate_mpin" android:title="Generate Mpin" android:icon="@drawable/gen_mpin_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/history" android:title="My History" android:icon="@drawable/history_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/acc_statement" android:title="Account Statement" android:icon="@drawable/acc_stat_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/funds" android:title="Funds" android:icon="@drawable/funds_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/game_rates" android:title="Game Rates" android:icon="@drawable/game_rates_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/how_to_play" android:title="How To Play" android:icon="@drawable/how_to_play_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/settings" android:title="Settings" android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/logout" android:title="Logout" android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"/>

</menu>
```

Below is the result I'm getting while using the above XML file:

What I getting:
[image: Reality]

What I expecting:
[image: Expectation]